# How to associate a role to a user using the event listener in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

A user has a single role, whereas a role has many users. So the below is my relationship.

**User Model**

```
public function role() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}
```

**Role Model**

```
public function users() {
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

I can associate a role to a user using the below piece of code by using the associate method in the seeders. But I cannot assign a role to a user using the events and listeners, which executes when a user creates an account.

**User Seeder**

```
$client = User::create([
    'name' => 'Client',
    'email' => 'client@localhost.com',
    'password' => Hash::make('password'),
]);
$client - > role() - > associate('3');
$client - > save();
```

**User-Created Listener**

```
public function handle(UserCreatedEvent $event) {
    // Assigning Client Role To The User
    $event - > user - > role() - > associate('3') - > save();

    // User Successfully Registered - Welcome Mail
    Mail::to($event - > user - > email) - > send(new UserCreatedMail($event - > user));
}
```

Comment: welcome mail is working fine?

Comment: @bhucho yes its working fine, It’s just I am unable to associate role with users. I am able to associate a role with a user in seeders, but unable to do the same through event listener. The mail is also working absolutely fine, just the role.

Comment: The associate method sets the foreign key for the value you insert, so I guess it is not returning the model for you to insert, so try to save() it in separate steps, `$event->user->role()->associate('3');` then `$event->user->save();`

Comment: you can check by doing `dd($event - > user - > role() - > associate('3'))` to see what is returned

Comment: @bhucho I tried the above one already, but its the same. Yet to dd, will try that.